# Is there an Intellij shortcut like Eclipse's "Select Next Element"?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, textselection

Is there any editor command in Intellij **that could provide the same selection change like "Select Next Element in Eclipse"** (actually expands the selection to the left/rigth elements)? This would be very handy.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Fh6YWuK.gif]

Comment: Have you tried "Edit | Extend selection"?

Comment: That goes up one level, not left or right.

Comment: Currently it's not possible in IDEA. Feel free to create feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA